# Use of an already created cookie to get content via php script

Tags: php, cookies

I have regular credentials to access a specific site (built with OpenCMS).
Everyday I download (Save AS) a bunch of pages, parse them and extract the data I need.
Is there a way to do it via PHP? Maybe using the cookie that's already been set?
Or passing credentials in http request? (I tried but seems OpenCMS won't allow that).
I've seen something about stream_context_create but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: this will login and gather data for you: https://github.com/Pamblam/Crawler

Comment: @PootieTang Thanks, but I can't _Upload the files to your server and run_ as stated in Usage. Server is not mine

Comment: you don't nee dto upload it to their server, download wamp or something and run it on your own computer

Comment: also, if you're better with javascript you can write a greaseemonkey script and just run it in the browser..

Comment: Ah Ok. Now I get what you mean. Yes, I have XAMMP installed on localhost. I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on CURL. You can specify a cookie jar to use, which means you can copy your normal browser cookies into the file CURL is using.